# Sort list of lists by min/max in Python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, nested-lists

I apologize for a simple question, but I cannot find an answer to it in the archives.
what should i do to sort smaller lists within a larger list.
for example

`lst=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5,9,8,7], [9, 0, 1, 2, 3 ]]`

should return

`[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5,7,8,9]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3,9 ]`

I tried to use lambda 
`lst.sort(key=lambda x: x.min())`
and sorted 
`lst.sort(key=lambda x: sorted(x))`
but neither works. could you please direct me a little bit. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: I don't see the min/max requirement in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Keep it simple, just use a list comprehension and sort the list inside the list:

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 9]]
```

So, with respect to your code, you can just do this:

```
lst = [sorted(x) for x in lst]
```

Comment: Just a gripe on notation, I'd always reserve `i` for integer indexes, and use something like `x` when naming a piece of data. Only my taste, though, upvoted anyway.

Comment: @machineyearning changed. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to sort each sublist, then assign back to your main list

```
>>> lst = [sorted(i) for i in lst]
>>> lst
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
lst=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5,9,8,7], [9, 0, 1, 2, 3 ]]
for x in lst:
    x.sort()
```

I looped through `lst` and sorted each inner list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
>>> list(map(sorted, lst))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function:

```
def sort_lst(lst):
    lists = []
    for l in lists:
       l = l[:] 
       l.sort()
       lists.append(l)
    return lists
```

or

```
 l = [[1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 5, 6]]
 l.sort(key=lambda x: x.sort())
 print(l)
 Output: [[1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort in place, you can do something like this:

```
any(ll.sort() for ll in lst)
```

(`any` is really only there to ditch the return values, which are all `None`; it will return `false`.)